# How to run SQL in shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

How do you run a SQL command in a shell script while setting a variable?  I had tried this method and it isn't executing the command, it is thinking the command is just a string.

```
#!/bin/ksh
variable1=`sqlplus -s username/pw@oracle_instance <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
select count(*) from table;
EXIT;
EOF`
if [ -z "$variable1" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned from database"
  exit 0
else
  echo $variable1
fi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh
variable1=$( 
echo "set feed off
set pages 0
select count(*) from table;
exit
"  | sqlplus -s username/password@oracle_instance
)
echo "found count = $variable1"
```

Comment: Self-answering and then self-commenting?

Comment: @Aneri, not sure if you've used SO before, but writing a question and adding an answer that doesn't exist in SO is adding value to SO. It is actually a feature.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). e.g. from a prompt:

```
$ sqlplus -s username/password@oracle_instance <<EOF
set feed off
set pages 0
select count(*) from table;
exit
EOF
```

so `sqlplus` will consume everything up to the `EOF` marker as stdin.

Comment: I was able to get something like this to execute, but it was having difficulty with setting the result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for answering but, there's a working code:

```
sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" << EOF
    SET HEADING OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET LINESIZE 3800
    SET TRIMSPOOL ON
    SET TERMOUT OFF
    SET SPACE 0
    SET PAGESIZE 0
    select (select instance_name from v\$instance) as DB_NAME,
           file_name
      from dba_data_files
     order by 2;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this has EOF at the end (to avoid a warning)?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo on;
set serveroutput on;

connect <SCHEMA>/<PASS>@<HOST>:<PORT>/<SID>;

truncate table tmp;

exit;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
PL_CONNECT_STRING="$DB_USERNAME/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SERVICE"

OUTPUT=$(sqlplus -s $PL_CONNECT_STRING <<-END-OF-SQL
           select count(*) from table;
exit;
END-OF-SQL)
echo "COMPLETED GATHER STATS $OUTPUT";
```

**Explanation:**

`PL_CONNECT_STRING` carry database username, password and it service name

sqlplus is used to connect the Database with `PL_CONNECT_STRING` details

`END-OF-SQL` tag contain the query which you want to execute

`echo` is used to print the output of the query

NOTE: You can give multiple Query inside the `END-OF-SQL` tag, so its useful for batch execution as well