# Performing SQL operations within Function in shell script

Tags: sql, function, shell

I am new to shell scripting and trying to write some sql operations inside function and based on the output I need to return a value from function . Is it possible to achieve this using shell script ?

I tried to google it but somehow I am not getting anything related to sql operation in function.

Any sample will be appreciable .

Comment: Literally the first google result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182286/how-to-run-sql-in-shell-script

Comment: @JacobH, Hi Jacob the sql statements are working fine in normal script , however will it work withing the function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run SQL in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182286/how-to-run-sql-in-shell-script)